# Bay Trail pad and buggy Elementary OS installation

Tags: settings, themes, touchscreen

installed yesterday elementary OS to my tablet. Theme is buggy, some buttons and text is missing. I can't change display settings, pressing that button do nothing. Windows does not fit on screen, so I need solution to scale them thinner.

After I upgrade kernel from 3.19.0-32-generic to 3.19.0-58-generic I lost touchscreen. How to fix this? **edit: I upgrade kernel to 4.4.0-18, touchscreen fixed.**

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

I just tested elementary OS Loki and these problems where gone. So tablet users should install Loki.